# How do you make a for-loop array gives a single, non-continuous output in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, decrement

I'm making a program that, right now, uses hitboxes to track if the player and an object collide, but cannot figure out how to make the player lose just 1 health when this happens.

If necessary, the "objects" variable is initiated as an empty array, but objects are added to it with a button. Both the "objects" and "player" variables are created with the Hitbox constructor:

```js
function Hitbox(x, y, w, h) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.width = w;
 this.height = h;
 this.speedX = 0;
 this.speedY = 0;
 this.gravity = 0.05;
 this.gravitySpeed = 0;
 this.update = function() {
  ctx = area.context;
  ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 }
 this.newPos = function() {
  this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
  this.x += this.speedX;
  this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
  this.hitBottom();
  this.hitSide();
 }
 this.hitBottom = function() {
  if(this.y > (ground - this.height)) {
   this.y = (ground - this.height);
  }
 }
 this.hitSide = function() {
  if(this.x < 0) {
   this.x = 0;
  }else if(this.x > window.innerWidth - this.width) {
   this.x = window.innerWidth - this.width;
  }
 }
     this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
         var myleft = this.x;
         var myright = this.x + (this.width);
         var mytop = this.y;
         var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
         var otherleft = otherobj.x;
         var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
         var othertop = otherobj.y;
         var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
         var crash = true;
         if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
             crash = false;
         }
         return crash;
     }
}
```

In the updateArea() function, which runs for every interval, I created a for loop that runs through all the current objects in the "objects" variable and tests for their collision with the player.

```js
 for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  if(player.crashWith(objects[i])) {
   health--;
  }
 }
```

If this is true, the player's health, displayed above the player hitbox, SHOULD decrement by 1. INSTEAD, it instantaneously depletes all of the health, even though it is an if statement, not a while statement.

Is it possible to use this method to decrease the "health" variable by 1, or should I use another way entirely?

Comment: Look at array methods like [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): `if (objects.some(crashWithPlayer)) health -= 1`

Comment: It sounds like the problem is you're subtracting 1 health for every frame they're colliding rather than just the first frame they're colliding.

Comment: You can use a timestamp to set the last time the player lost health and give it a X seconds of being immune until it can lose health again.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by keeping track of whether or not the player's collision has already been handled:

```js
let collision = false;
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  if(player.crashWith(objects[i])) {
    collision = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(collision) {
  if(!player.isAlreadyColliding) {
    health--;
    player.isAlreadyColliding = true;
  }
} else {
  player.isAlreadyColliding = false;
}
```

This way, only the first collision causes lost health. Collisions that happen in subsequent frames are ignored unless they follow a frame where no collision occurred.

Another alternative is to end the collision on the frame its detected by moving the player so they're not colliding during the next frame.